# Linq to SQL - calculating a property on object returned by query

Tags: linq-to-sql

I've got a query that returns a set of objects, events in this case...

Now I want to set a value on these events from the return value of a scalar database function. I've tried doing this using a function in code to set the property, but I'm getting an 'has no supported translation to SQL.' error which makes sense (as there it's not possible to translate this code into SQL), but how can I do this ?

I want to return objects of event type so an anonymous type projection is no good.

Here's some code :

```
var query = (from e in db.Events 
             select SetDistanceProperty(
                   e, db.DistanceBetween(lat, lon, e.Latitude, e.Longitude)));

private static Event SetDistanceProperty(Event e, double? distance)
{
    if(distance != null)
        e.DistanceFromLocation = (double)distance;
    return e;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could query an in-memory collection instead:

```
(from e in db.Events.ToList() 
    select  SetDistanceProperty(e, 
              db.DistanceBetween(lat, lon, 
                   e.Latitude, e.Longitude)));
```